# How to copy Elasticsearch data to SQL Server

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, elasticsearch, kibana

I want to send data from kibana(Elasticsearch) to mysql.
Is there any simple way to do so directly or if it possible through python?

Comment: yes, there is a simple way: at first you start solving a problem and ask if something specific doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 0):

I think the whole task can be divided into two parts:

1. how to fetch the data from elasticsearch (you can do it via python): https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/
2. how to add data to mysql (you can do it via python):
   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html

Btw, you can check this page to find out the sample script for getting all documents from one index in ES via python: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/get-all-documents-from-an-index/86977

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called an ETL, I am not giving an exact answer, since your question is more general.

You can develop a small Python script to achieve this, but in general, this is more useful to use a real ETL.

I recommend Apache Spark, with the official elasticsearch-hadoop plugin:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html
- https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html#write-data-to-jdbc

Exemple in Scala (but you could use Python or Java or R):

```
val df = sqlContext.read().format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").load("spark/trips")

df.write.jdbc(jdbcUrl, "_table_")
```

The benefits:

- Spark will distribute work via workers (will read all elasticsearch
  shards in same time!)
- Handle failover
- Let you modify data